# Firebase Custom Login JWT Status

Tags: firebase, jwt

We're planning on using Firebase custom login for an app.  Creating JWTs is well documented and very clear.  However, what isn't clear is the status of the JWT, is this token still valid? did the user login to Firebase? etc.

Is there a way to find the status of a JWT using the same server that created the JWT?

Anything helps, thanks!

I'm using the following to create my token.

```
function generateFirebaseLoginToken(userData){
    var tokenData = {
        'uid': userData.id,
        'id': userData.id,
        'email': userData.email,
        'locale': userData.locale,
        'username': userData.username
    };
    var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator(secret);
    var token = tokenGenerator.createToken(tokenData);
    console.log(token);
    return token;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) contain an `expires_at` field that can be used to statically determine whether or not a given token has been expired.

In order to verify the signature, you'll either need the public key corresponding to the token signature (if the token was signed via an asymmetric keypair) or the secret key (if the token was signed via a symmetric key as in the case of Firebase).

For Firebase JWTs, you would need the Firebase secret to verify the signature. With that in hand, you could use any open-source JWT helper library to confirm the signature. Check out http://jwt.io/ for some of those libs.

Comment: I have the Firebase secret, that is how I'm creating the JWT.  How would I then get the expires_at field from the returned token?  I added my generatedToken function to my Question.

Comment: @Aaron Check out [https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) for a Node library that can verify the validity of a JWT based upon shared secret and expiration time.

Answer (score 0):

First you should call this API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/createAuthUri?key=
{
    "identifier":"",
    "continueUri":""    
}
```

Go over with this other:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=
{
"email":"",
"password":"",
"returnSecureToken":true    
}
```

the Key parameter you get from apiKey associated with a single Firebase project.